# CSS media queries not working on mobile, but work on desktop

Tags: html, css, node.js, responsive-design, media-queries

I have added the meta tags in my HTML

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0," />
```

My media queries are in the right order and at the end of the stylesheet. (Desktop version works)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/* my refactoring code */
}
```

Desktop version looks like this>
[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAtci.png)

Mobile version looks like this>
[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4W3R.jpg)

Please help me get my code right for the mobile devices. Thank you!

Comment: try with only media like `@media (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: Tried that to no effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app was responsive on my localhost. But wasn't working when it was being served through AWS Elastic beanstalk. Because the HTML file was being rendered inside a frameset and the "meta tag" was missing in the beanstalk's served file header

[image: Source of served app by AWS Beanstalk]

Answer (score 2):

be sure the device you are using to test the mobile version is <= 600px.

You can try to use only @media :

```
@media ( max-width:600px ) {
 /* CSS rules here */
}
```

Or maybe use em instead of pixels :

```
@media only screen and (max-width:37.5em) { 
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```

---

Based on your feedback in comments, I wrote a snippet for you:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.myDiv {
  background-color: red;
  /* Other Desktop CSS Rules */
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 600px) {
  .myDiv {
    background-color: green;
    /* Other Small Devices CSS Rules */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='myDiv'>
  That's an amazing div.
</div>
```

Comment: using a 417px width mobile. Tried @media only to no effect. :(

Comment: Let's try the iPhone media query : 
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

Comment: tried  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) , that doesn't work too :(

Answer (score 2):

I remember working on a project and I had this problem.

Someone told me to replace:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0," />
```

And change it to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

At least this was what solved my problem.

This website has a little bit more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try media for mobile and tablet -

```
@media ( min-width: 320px ) and ( max-width: 480px ) {  
  /* your CSS */  
}
```

For more detail read below link

[link Here](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)